# Can I use "Heroic Effort" benefit with a reroll?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, powers

I've just found this item:

> **Couters of Second Chances** (Adv I 116):
>
> **Power (Daily)**
>       Free Action. Use this power when you miss with a melee attack. 
>       Reroll the attack, and use the second result, even if it’s lower.

And I was wondering if I could use it with the Human Racial Power "Heroic Effort":

> **Heroic Effort** (Heroes of The Forgotten Kingdoms 264):
>
> **Power (encounter)
>
>       Trigger**: You miss with an attack or fail a saving throw.
>       **Effect**: You gain a +4 racial bonus to the attack roll or the saving throw.

Let's suppose I miss an attack and I choose to reroll it with the item's daily power. If I also choose to use the Heroic Effort power, can I apply its benefit to the reroll result? Assume the first result was too low for the use of Heroic Effort making sense.

The order of the actions would be:

1. Make an attack roll;
2. miss first attack roll;
3. use second chance;
4. reroll;
5. use heroic effort on the second roll.

Comment: Are you talking about using Heroic Effort *before* or *after* the roll of the Second Chance die? You can't apply it *before* but you can apply it *after*

Comment: Could you clarify the usage limits on "Heroic Effort"? Is it at-will, encounter, daily, etc?

Comment: The order would be. 1) Make an attack roll; 2) miss first attack roll; 3) use second chance; 4) reroll; 5) use heroic effort on the second roll... is clearer?

Comment: I have two answers that say the opposite. Which one is right?

Comment: It's a daily power, you can't use it on both rolls. The answers are different because they're guessing differently about which roll you're asking about. Which one do you want to use it on?

Comment: Second chance is a daily power that I use on my first roll, so I can have a chance to reroll. On the reroll I intend to use Heroic Effort.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, and especially for putting it into the question where that belongs. I misread it; that makes it easier to read. :)

Comment: @user3347814 best I can tell the original first answer was under the impression that the second scenario in my answer was what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Provided you mean after the second roll is rolled. If the you applied it to the first roll, it's spent.

Here is the order of operations, to show how this works with the trigger:

1. Roll melee Attack.
2. Check if you missed.
3. If you missed, use Second Chance as a free action
4. Reroll via Second Chance.
5. Check if you missed.
6. Use Heroic Effort.

The trigger for Heroic Effort is *very much* in force and available with the second roll. You've just rolled and missed.

However, if instead you used it in the following order:

1. Roll melee Attack.
2. Check if you missed.
3. Use Heroic Effort.
4. If you still missed, use Second Chance as a free action
5. Reroll via Second Chance.
6. Check if you missed.
7. Heroic effort was expended already, so cannot be used here on a miss.

The other [answer here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/41427/1084), assumes this scenario to be the case and is correct in that instance, but it seems unclear from the context of the question which is under discussion.

Comment: I think the other answer read the question as "Roll melee attack. Check if you missed. You miss. Roll Second Chance, with a +4 bonus because of Heroic Effort" which would, indeed, be invalid. I'm not sure which the OP meant though

Comment: @Yamikuronue updated my answer to speak to both situations. Definitely more unclear than I realized and I've tried to reach out to the OP to clarify.